# Is there any benefit to prolong the King Leo batle with SFX Magic?

Tags: final-fantasy-9

at the beginning of the game when the Tantalus Theater Troupe from Lindblum performs *I Want to be Your Canary* the crew have access to a type of SFX Magic which does no damage, after the performance and crash in the Evil Forest this magic is removed.

considering you have to deal so much damage to end the battle with "King Leo" and this is only done with proper Attacks is there any benefit to prolonging the battle here with Stage Magic rather than simply having everyone attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't, other than for roleplaying purposes. All SFXs do 0 damage no matter what, and you can't steal either.

It doesn't influence the rest of the play either (The Swordfight*).

---

*Mini-game where Zidane and Blank have a duel with swords which grants you money & items